# How do I add an integer variable to an integer value in a class?

Tags: c#, integer, global-variables

I have a public variable stored in a class that is accessible through a constructor and would like to know how I can take an integer value returned by a number generator and add it to the variable's int value. Ex:

the class container

```
    public class Values
    {
        public static Values myValues = new Values();
    
        public int myNumber = 5;
    }
```

generator in separate class/method

```
    public static Values myValues = new Values();
    public static void theMethod()
    {
        Random randNum = new Random();
        
        int numGain;
        numGain = randNum.Next(1, 6);
    }
```

I basically want the generated value of numGain to add to the value of myNumber.

Comment: Note that `myValues` in `Values` is a different instance of `myValues` in your "separate class/method", meaning that they each have their own value of `myNumber`, so changes made to `Values.myValues.myNumber` won't be reflected in `myValues.myNumber` in the class that declares `theMethod()`.

Comment: When you say "add an integer variable", I'm assuming you want to add the two values. That's as simple as `myValues.myNumber = myValues.myNumber + numGain;`.

Comment: Thank you! I figured it was a simple thing.

Comment: Side note: don't declare a new `Random` inside your method. There are pitfalls to doing so. Declare it as a static field instead

Answer (score 3):

It sounds as if you want your `Values` class to keep track of the sum of numbers, is that correct? If so, it might be better to do something like this:

```
public class Values
{
    private int myNumber = 0; // Default value set to 0

    public int Add(int input){
        myNumber += input; // Increases myNumber by input

        return myNumber; // Return the new sum if you want to. 
    }

    // If you need the number without changing it:
    public int GetValue() { return myNumber; } 
}
```

Using that:

```
public static Values myValues = new Values();

public static void TheMethod()
{
    Random randNum = new Random();
    
    int numGain = randNum.Next(1, 6);

    // Now add the number to the instance of Values created above:
    myValues.Add(numGain); 
}
```